# localstorage in an incremental game

Tags: jquery

i don't understand how to use local storage to save the clicks.

Can you help me out and give me an example how to automaticaly save the game very 5 minutes or on a buttonclick? 
I need help with loading these saves too.
I set the evoAmount (my currency) to 1000 per click for testing purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? You already seem to be using setInterval() to call your functions. LocalStorage is quite easy to use, you should read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or some [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Setting a variable each 5 minutes is as easy as

```
setInterval(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('savedValueKey','savedValue');
},5*60*1000();
```

To set it on click you may use something like

```
$('#theButton').click(function() {
    ocalStorage.setItem('savedValueKey','savedValue');
});
```

In order to get the variable saved, you can use

```
var theValue = localStorage.getItem('savedValueKey');
```

Remember that the storage capacity varies for each browser.

Comment: So if want to save evoAmount then i would use:

`code`setInterval(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('evoAmountKey','evoAmount');
    },5*60*1000();


But what if i want to use it for "miner"? apparently i cant use "miner.Cost" or "miner.Amount"

Comment: if you use 'evoAmount' you are saving the string. If you want to save a variable called evoAmount you don't need to use the quotes.

See here for a working fiddle that saves miner.Amount: https://jsbin.com/hejokahuzi/edit?js,console